# I'm looking for a suitable database to store social media comments hierarchically

Tags: database, nosql

I want to develop a comment manager for a social media platform.

As usual for social media, creators can upload media and other users can comment these media. My goal is to download all comments for all media of specific creators and to store them hierarchically.

Target structure:

```
-> Creator (user name, user ID) -> Media object (media ID) -> Comment (user name, comment)
                                                           -> Comment (user name, comment)
                                                           -> ...
                                -> Media object (media ID) -> Comment (user name, comment)
                                                           -> Comment (user name, comment)
                                                           -> ...
                                -> ...
-> Creator (user name, user ID) -> ...
-> ...
```

I expect to store a few 'Creators', each with hundreds of 'Media objects' while every 'Media object' has around 10,000 comments of different users. Although I have made good expiriences with GT.M, I want to use another database this time and I tend to NoSQL databases because I can't think of an appropriate ERM for this data structure (large tables → low speed).

Do you have any suggestions of (free) databases to realize this data structure appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't know whether or not this question is suitable for stackoverflow, but here's my answer. Using a no server solution like Firebase will be incredibly easy, you'll just need to learn about firebase security rules properly. It is also possible to make desired structures in firebase, the price is free but if you're putting a lot of comments (or anything) then you'll have to pay. You can also try AWS however that is a lot more harder than firebase. Good luck!